# Observable change subscriber on error

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, project-reactor

How to change subscriber on error? I have a cold stream from database to consume. See the following case:

```
return coctailBundleStream
        .doOnNext(c -> {
          hostnames.add(c.get(KEY_HOSTNAME)); // [A]

          sendToOutboundQueue(c.get(KEY_CREDS));
          archiveSentMessage(c.get(KEY_CREDS), c.get(KEY_MESSAGE_ID));
        })
        .doOnComplete(this::saveCutOffTime)
        .doOnError(e -> informUserImpactedHostnames(hostnames, 
            theRestOfHostnamesInside(credsXmlStream, e))) // I don't think this is right
        .onErrorResumeNext(Flowable.empty())
        .count();
```

I want to send all hostnames impacted by the failure. But, see my comment above. I don't think this is correct, as the stream is consumed twice. For example if the implementation of `theRestOfHostnamesInside` is `credsStream.map(c -> c.getHostname()), e)`

I think, ideally, the error handler should continue the stream using another subscription which extract the rest of the hostnames into a list then append the list with the previous list (see line marked with [A]).

Answer (score 0):

`onErrorResumeNext` should be used to provide the flowable that you want to fallback to.

However, the main difficulty is to avoid duplicates. if the source is cold as you say, you'll re-do a DB request and if the originally subscribed sequence emitted some data before it errored, then the same data will be re-emitted.

You can alleviate that by chaining `distinct` after the `onErrorResumeNext` (you should be able to provide a `keySelector` to indicate how to detect duplicates). BUT you have to make sure to use a criteria that wouldn't mark two elements from the source as duplicates (so as to ONLY eliminate the duplicates created by the retry).

Other way around that is to store the keys already processed yourself in a collection and filter these out in the `onErrorResumeNext`, but you have to make sure said collection is specific to each `subscribe` made downstream of the `count()`... So not that easy.

Comment: I don't like the idea of re-doing the same DB request. It seems not efficient to me.

Comment: it depends on what the original error is, but yeah you could instead fallback on a second sequence that only queries the missing keys... since `onErrorResumeNext` concatenates the data from the errored sequence (if any) with the data from the fallback sequence, this fits the bill

Answer (score 0):

You could do it just inside of a flatMap

```
        Observable.fromIterable(yourList)
            .flatMap(x ->{
                Observable.just(x)
                        .map(data -> yourNormalSave(data))
                        .onErrorReturn(errorResult)
            })
            .subscribe(result ->{
                        if(result != errorResult)
                            count++;
                        eles{
                        //error received here
                        }  
            }
            );
```

So inside of flatMap, if you meet an error it will change it into normal type but downstream has no idea of it. So your downstream subscriber consume them in onNext aswell. You can do it properly instead of `x -> Observable.just(x)`  I just put them there as an example.